# Can I get the ProductCode from an InstallShield executable?

Tags: c#, installshield

I can programmatically query an MSI and retrieve such properties as the ProductCode.
Is there a way to query an Installshield executable to get the properties of the MSI that it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess installshield executable is kind of a self extracting executable. It first extracts files to a temp folder and then runs the setup. If the exe supports commandline switch to extract all the files then you can make it extract through your program and then query the MSI for product code.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'm new to InstallShield so learning as I go. If it's a self-extracting exe then I guess I'm screwed as far as querying it goes, without first extracting it...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run your executable with the logging enabled:

```
Setup.exe /v"/l*v C:\MSI.log"
```

And then search for a ProductCode in the created log file.